# Linux: routing table - Gateway column: 0.0.0.0 vs *?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have found SO question about [What does 0.0.0.0 gateway mean in routing table?](https://superuser.com/questions/872479/what-does-0-0-0-0-gateway-mean-in-routing-table) but this is not exactly what I want to know. I have noticed that in some outputs (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599424/understanding-routing-table-entry)) of Linux `route -n` command there are `*` under `Gateway` column while in other outputs (e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/622750/does-the-order-of-entries-in-the-routing-table-matter)) there are `0.0.0.0` under `Gateway` column. From those outputs I can conclude that: `*` are shown when `Iface` is physical interface while `0.0.0.0` are shown when `Iface` is IP address. Can you confirm this?

Can you please also clarify when to use physical interface as `Iface` and when to use IP address? I suppose physical interface can be only used on links that have two-ends i believe those are known as point-to-point links (in other words it is not suitable e.g. when you have multiple possible hosts on the other site e.g. when you are connected to switch) am I right?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing.

Your second example is with the `-n` option, asking `route -n` to show IP addresses directly, while the first one lets it translate addresses to names – note how it also shows `default` in place of `0.0.0.0` for the destination, and so on.

In both cases, it means that there *isn't* a gateway – the route destination is on-link and the OS will try to reach these hosts directly.

Such routes work just fine on Ethernet/WiFi, too – the sender will use ARP or ND to learn the destination's MAC address. In fact, that's how you and your gateway reach each other! See also https://superuser.com/a/763375/1686.

---

Generally, on Linux, avoid `route` & `ifconfig` and use modern tools like `ip route` instead.